Sideloading question (iOS): How to fix 'integrity could not be verified"?
trying to sideload onto my iphone, but cant get anything to install. i keep getting things along the lines of "could not be installed because the app's integrity cannot be verified". can someone tell me how to fix this?
**
remember: i am not using testflight or anything hence this because nobody has reported this issue as a developer. this is just simple sideloading for personal use **
tried to sideload ipa, worked (appears on the home screen), but doesnt install upon tapping it.

How is the app signed?  You can't just install arbitrary apps on iOS - It either needs to be signed by Apple (App Store/TestFlight), signed by an Enterprise certificate (which your device trusts) or signed with a developer certificate (and the IPA file needs to include your device UDID in the embedded provisioning profile)
